# Resizing a partition got stuck, what to do now?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to resize my Mac partition from 380 GB to 350 GB.
Disk utility didn't allow me to do that, claiming my current container size is also the minimum container size, despite having 130 GB of unused storage, so I used Terminal and these two methods:

First

```
  | cut -d. -f4 \
  | xargs -n1 tmutil deletelocalsnapshots
```

from [Can't resize APFS Container: Not enough free space in Container due to APFS limits or tidemarks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321533/cant-resize-apfs-container-not-enough-free-space-in-container-due-to-apfs-limi/321542#321542)

and then [Resize APFS partition in Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345483/resize-apfs-partition-in-mojave/391431#391431)

Initially that seemed to work, but it got stuck at some point, showing this:

```
Started APFS operation
Aligning shrink delta to 30,068,936,704 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 349,999,996,928 bytes
Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 261,254,807,552 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l -S /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Macintosh HD - Daten was formatted by hfs_convert (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Preboot was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Recovery was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume VM was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by diskmanagementd (1412.101.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the extent ref tree
Checking the fsroot tree
Verifying allocated space
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 380,068,933,632 to 349,999,996,928 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
[ \ 0%..10%..20%..30%..40%............................... ] 45.0%
```

I left it overnight (twice), since it might take some time, but after about 40 hours I'm starting to feel a bit nervous.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance