# Removing non-APFS partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I have a Mac mini, 2012. Some time ago, I needed to run Mojave, so I partitioned the SSD into 2, 256MB each, and got this running.

[image]

I'm having some issues (when powering up, holding the option key doesn't give me boot choices, and getting Mojave running is tedious) and I'd like to wipe the existing Yosemite partition.

To me, the brute force method, would be:

- Boot from external drive
- Use CCC to clone the Mojave system
- Wipe the SSD 100%, and format as APFS
- Clone the Mojave System back over

Before I spend the time to do this, my question is:

Is there a way to resize the Mojave/APFS partition to the whole drive, in place, and wipe out the Yosemite partition?

I am looking at Disk Utility, and don't see how I'd do this.

Update: I CCC'd an image of the Yosemite drive, and wiped it. Now I see this

[image]

I am able to click the "-" to remove the Mojave partition, but when I highlight Yosemite, the "-" is greyed out. Note: I am booted up from an external drive. Also, when I erased the Yosemite partition I made it APFS, hoping that would help.

Is there a non-terminal 'next step' I can use?

Comment: You can use `diskutil` from **Terminal** to perform operations not available to **Disk Utility**.  In **Terminal** type `diskutil`, then _right-click_ on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345483/resize-apfs-partition-in-mojave

Answer (score 1):

The linked question in the comment was useful. It convinced me that trying to manipulate APFS partitions in place was not going to be easy, and likely not work at all.

In the end, I used the process I described in the question, i.e. CCC did a beautiful job making a clone of the drive, I wiped both partitions, but had to reformat to Mac OS extended to re-partition, and then once there was the one partition, reformatted to APFS.

While I like the idea of being to boot into multiple older OS, it's less practical to do it on partitioned drives given how APFS functions.