# APFS Containers - Encapsulation and Safety

Tags: disk-utility, partition, apfs, disk-volume

I'm eager to use `Containers` not `Volumes` on APFS to add beta versions of macOS to my dev machine.

I want as much separation and encapsulation as possible because I don't want the OS's to interfere with each other.

I have read that multiple betas on separate `Volumes` on the same APFS `Container` can cause issues.

Thus I was aiming to make multiple `Containers` on the same internal disk.

1. Is adding and removing `Containers` through disk utility safe and effective? (Apple seems to only champion Volumes in it's docs: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891.
2. Is using `Containers` in this way providing maximum encapsulation from a logical perspective? (to avoid issues like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/hea72p/warning_do_not_install_big_sur_on_the_same_apfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

Yes, you can add and remove containers without causing problems. You have to be aware that two containers cannot share space in the same way two volumes in a container do.

It is probable that this would totally encapsulate the two OS installs, but be aware that until Big Sur we thought the same about different volumes in a single copntainer so if it will continue to work *after* Big Sur in subsequent beta versions is an open question.

Comment: I wonder why using containers over volumes isn’t preferred. Seems much more tidy to me.